# Check loaded shared libraries from another shared library on Linux/Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

Is it possible to check which shared libraries are loaded by the calling process from another shared library (.so)? I know there are command line tools for that, but is it possible to perform such a check in C++ code?

I need to somehow get the list of native shared libraries loaded by an Android application, but it doesn't seem to be possible from a Java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `/proc/<pid>/maps` file or just `/proc/self/maps` for the calling process: lines that ends with '.so' are for linked shared libraries. It's a hack, but should work. Note that one library could be mapped multiple times so you need to skip the repetitions.

And good news: you could do it from java. The code snippet below prints shared libraries for the current process to the logcat.

```
try {
    Set<String> libs = new HashSet<String>();
    String mapsFile = "/proc/self/maps";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mapsFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.endsWith(".so")) {
            int n = line.lastIndexOf(" ");
            libs.add(line.substring(n + 1));
        }
    }
    Log.d("Ldd", libs.size() + " libraries:");
    for (String lib : libs) {
        Log.d("Ldd", lib);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Do some error handling...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do some error handling...
}
```

The output on my device is:

```
D/Ldd     (11286): 55 libraries:
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libc.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libdbus.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/librpc.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libEGL.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libstagefright_color_conversion.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libmedia.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libemoji.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libstagefright_avc_common.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libskiagl.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libopencore_player.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libjpeg.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger_client.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libstagefright.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libdrm1.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libwebcore.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libhardware.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libexif.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libgps.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/liblog.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libexpat.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libopencore_common.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libbluedroid.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libm.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libicui18n.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libomx_amrenc_sharedlibrary.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libwpa_client.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libstdc++.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libz.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libETC1.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libsonivox.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libstlport.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libutils.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libicudata.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libsqlite.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libhardware_legacy.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libpixelflinger.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libvorbisidec.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libcutils.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libui.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libomx_sharedlibrary.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libcamera_client.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libskia.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libopencore_net_support.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libnetutils.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libbinder.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libssl.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libicuuc.so
D/Ldd     (11286): /system/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

Also if necessary pid could be obtained by `android.os.Process.myPid()`.

Comment: No, you don't need any command line tool for this. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great example! But it shows me an error: The method myPid() is undefined for the type Process...

Comment: OK, I get it, just need to call android.os.Process.myPid()

Comment: Yea, you right about `Process`. I updated the answer (for others) so as not to be confused with `java.lang.Process`.

Comment: You can also just use `/proc/self` instead of going through bothering with `Process.myPid()`; `self` is a symlink to the current PID

Comment: That's true, thank you. I've missed that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

WRT java, start a process to call [ldd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) on the .so in question.  Capture the output from stdout and process the output:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ldd a.so");  
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream());  
outputGobbler.start();  
process.waitFor();  
String result = outputGobbler.buffer;
```

Refer to the seminal post on [StreamGobbler](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) for a class definition.  I added a `String buffer` variable and replaced this line, `System.out.println(type + ">" + line);`, with this `buffer = buffer + line+"\n";` in the class definition from the previous link.  I also, obviously, dropped the second argument to the constructor.

```
class StreamGobbler extends Thread
{
    InputStream is;
    String buffer;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.buffer = "";
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line=null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                buffer += line+"\n";    
            } catch (IOException ioe)
              {
                ioe.printStackTrace();  
              }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `ldd` command in the standard (unmodified) Android system.

Comment: No `nm` too. No even `grep` or `find` or most of the other standard UNIX tools. You could check it in emulator.

Comment: Sorry, I was basing my responses on the `linux` tag.  I don't have any android experience or an emulator.